# clean previous data and cache automatically while installing new apk

Tags: android, caching

we 're currently developing android program. What we need to do, every time the user install new (update) apk, the installation process include clean the data and cache of previous installed apk.

How can we do that?

Appreciate for the help

Answer (score 0):

set allowBackup to false in manifest application tag i.e.

```
<application
 ...
 android:allowBackup="false"
 ... >
```

Hope it will work for you.